# connecting to a different IP if failed the first time python sockets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

Not able to connect a different IP after being able to connect the first time

```
class Client():
  def __init__(self):
       self.host = None
       self.ip = None
       self.error_count = 0
       self._load_ip()
       self._load_certs()
       self._build_context()
       self.connect()

  def _load_ip(self):
       self.ip = '19x.x.4'
       self.port = xxxx
  def _load_certs(self):
       self.cert = '/path/'
  def _build_context(self):
       self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_NET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
       self.context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
       self.context.load_verify_locations(self.cert)

  def connect(self):
       try:
           self.conn = self.context.wrap_socket(self.s, server_side=False)
           self.conn.connect((self.ip, self.port))
           return self.conn
       except Exception as ex:
           if self.error_count <=1:
              self.error_count +=1
              self.ip = '19x.x.5'
              self.conn.close() # close the previous connection
              self._build_context() # call this function again for new socket
              self.connect() # call the function again to try and connect to a different IP
           raise (f"Error connecting {ex}")
```

The Idea is that I want to try a different IP if the first IP does not work.  If there is any error then the Exception gets executed if the error count is <=1 and a different IP is added to the `self.ip` and the `connect()` function called again but it gives the following error:

*[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   try:
       ...
       self.conn.connect((self.ip, self.port))
       return self.conn
   except Exception as ex:
       if self.error_count <=1:
          ...
          self.connect() # call the function again to try and connect to a different IP
       raise (f"Error connecting {ex}")
```

While you try to connect to a different IP address after the first failed, you ignore that this new connect succeeded and still raise the error from the initial connection fail.

Comment: Thanks.  Did not realized that.